# What properties it is necessary to set view1, so that it fills the rest of the window?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

What properties it is necessary to set view1, so that it fills the rest of the window?

```
<Alloy>
   <Window>
      <View id="view1">

      </View>
      <View id="view2" height="50">

      </View>
   </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Alloy>
   <Window>
      <View id="view1" top="0" bottom="50" width="100%">
      </View>

      <View id="view2" height="50" bottom="0" width="100%">
      </View>
   </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Also it is good to put the dimensions in the style (TSS) file instead of putting them in the view XML file. If this resolves your query then mark it as an answer for the reference for the rest of the community.

Comment: how are you sure that he wants view2 at bottom? the question is unclear like how views are laid out.

Comment: @PrashantSaini With the minimal information provided and considering the current layout of the XML with View2 below View1, based on this I took the assumption and provided the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to fill dimensions. It depends on what kind of layout type you have used like - vertical, horizontal or composite (default).

**Vertical**

- Aligns children below each other.
- You can control width, left, right, top & bottom properties. (bottom property doesn't work for last child)
- Last child can occupy rest of the vertical height of parent.

---

**Horizontal:**

- Aligns children from left-to-right in horizontal plane.
- Can control left, right, top & bottom properties (right property doesn't work for last child).
- Last child can occupy remaining width of view

---

**Composite or default**

- Most flexible if you have not oriented UI.
- Can keep views anywhere using top,left,right,bottom.
- Assigning left & right only will define the width. Adding width with left & right will obey width keeping left & right restrictions.
  -- e.g. if left & right = 20 & width=Ti.UI.SIZE, then view will start from left & will have width as Ti.UI.SIZE & will not go beyond right=20
- Same rule as above applies for height as well.